# not able to focus to textbox after asp.net updatepanel postback

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I am using asp.net update panel for part of the page. I have a textbox outside of the updatepanel. This textbox is used to search for employees. If the user does some action inside the update panel that causes a postback and after the page is rendered I cannot click on the textbox to enter text. This happens in IE7. But in IE8 it works fine. I can enter the text in the textbox after the postback. Also, if I remove the update panel everything works fine in IE7 also. Did anyone experience this problem? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Can you place textbox inside update panel?

Comment: I cannot because it is in another control.

Answer (score 0):

How are you posting back when the user does something within the update panel?  I'd suggest doing a partial postback and not a full postback.  This may help your problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function doPartialPostBack()
  {
     __doPostBack('<%=UpdatePanel.ClientID %>', '');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: since the control is inside the updatepanel the request will be treated as partial postback. The updatepanel converts the full postback into partial postback automatically.